# Java recursive Generic and Wildcard

Tags: java, generics, recursion, wildcard

Hello i have a question about Java and using wildcard with recursive generics. I have the following interface

```
public interface Recursive<R extends Recursive<R>> {}
```

and another intrface which uses the recursive interface

```
public interface Use<R extends Recursive<R>> {}
```

now i have interface which looks like this

```
public interface Base<R extends Recursive<R>> {
    Use<R>[] getUses();
}
```

and based on that class i want a derived class which uses a wildcard like that

```
public class Derived extends Base<Recursive<?>> {
    Use<?>[] getUses();
}
```

which isnt allowed but how can i manage to say that my generic type is everything that fits?

Comment: What do you want to do in your derived class?  Does your code compile?

Comment: `Derived extends Base<Recursive>` should be enough.

Comment: but then i get a warning because i use a raw type is there a way without getting this warning?

Comment: You probably wanted `class Derived extends Base<Derived>`

Comment: Also, this recursive bound is very likely not necessary

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Recursive< ? >` doesn't satisfy the constraint on `Base`'s type parameter.

If you want to extend `Base< R >` you have to supply something for `R` which is also a `Recursive< R >`.  `Recursive< ? >` is not good enough because the compiler can't figure out that `Recursive< ? > extends Recursive< Recursive< ? > >`.

It doesn't really make sense to extend a `Base` of unknown type, but you can declare a heterogeneous collection of them:

```
Collection< Base< ? > > cb; // ok for some reason
Collection< Base< Recursive< ? > > > cbr; // not ok!
```

From your comment we know `Base` looks like

```
public abstract class Base< R extends Recursive< R > > {
    public abstract R[] foo();
}
```

For each qualifying `R` you can of course do

```
public class Derived< R extends Recursive< R > > extends Base< R > {
    @Override public R[] foo() {
        return ( R[] )new Object[] { r1, r2 };
    }
}
```

but it's not clear from your comment that this is what you want.  Do you know what the specific `R` is that you want `Derived` to use?

**EDIT** the following compiles.  would that suffice?

```
interface Recursive< R extends Recursive< R > > {}
abstract class Base< R extends Recursive< ? extends R > > {
    abstract public R[] foo();
}
class Derived extends Base< Recursive< ? > > {
    public Recursive< ? >[] foo() { return null; }
}
```

**EDIT 2** Adjusting for the change to the original post:

```
interface Recursive< R extends Recursive< R > > {}
interface Use< R extends Recursive< ? extends R > > {}
abstract class Base< R extends Recursive< ? extends R > > {
    abstract public Use< R >[] foo();
}
class Derived extends Base< Recursive< ? > > {
    @Override public Use< Recursive< ? > >[] foo() { return null; }
}
```

Comment: in the base class is a method which should return an array of R and in the derived class i need to return 2 different object which implement the given interface... so the super class of both is Recursive which i try to return an aray of...

Comment: the derived class should not be generic in my case since at that point i know which values belong in the array i need to return. the problem is the 2 values I try to return are of different class. So i know i need to return a array like this: `new Recursive<?>[]{}` but which parameter do i have to insert into the generic for base so i correctly override the method when returning `Recursive<?>[]`

Comment: Do these two types have any common superclass?

Comment: @MZuenni I have edited my answer, see if that will work for your case.

Comment: i have made the problem even more complex and can't make it work the way i want.... and the only common superclass they have is the recursive interface they both implement

Answer (score 0):

You need to type (with the right bound) your subclass, otherwise the compiler can't assert that the wildcard of the class is the *same* type as what your method returns, which is required.

Try this:

```
public class Derived<R extends Recursive<R>> extends Base<R> {
    Use<R>[] getUses();
}
```

Comment: as i already sayd derived should not be generic itself but implement the interface with a given type